# Printing a list of lists, without brackets

Tags: python, list, printing

A somewhat similar question was asked on here but the answers did not help.

I have a list of lists, specifically something like..

```
[[tables, 1, 2], [ladders, 2, 5], [chairs, 2]]
```

It is meant to be a simple indexer.

I am meant to output it like thus:

```
tables 1, 2
ladders 2, 5
chairs 2
```

I can't get quite that output though.

I can however get:

```
tables 1 2
ladders 2 5
chairs 2
```

But that isn't quite close enough.

Is there a simple way to do what I'm asking? This is not meant to be the hard part of the program.

Comment: show us what you tried and what you expect

Comment: You should show the **code** that you tried.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
for item in l:
  print item[0], ', '.join(map(str, item[1:]))
```

where `l` is your list.

For your input, this prints out

```
tables 1, 2
ladders 2, 5
chairs 2
```

Comment: @LarryLustig: As far as I can see, the output is *exactly* as the OP requested, down to spaces and commas.

Comment: I just tried this with:

    [['wind', 1, 2], ['blow', 1], ['form', 1], ['south', 1], 
    ['strong', 2]]

I got output of:    

    w i, n, d

Followed by a traceback error about why an int is not subscriptable

Comment: @user1079404: I've just tested the code on your list and it works. Make sure you're applying it to the entire list, not to each element.

Comment: @aix: My mistake, I was reading the actual, rather than desired, output.

Comment: Sorry, I see what I was doing wrong.

The code works fine, but, I don't understand is the way that "join" works, so it always adds the string (in this case ', ') on to the end of each string in the iteration?

Comment: @user1079404: It inserts the `, ` between consecutive elements. See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: Yup I get it now thanks. Had to look up the python docs for "map" too but that also makes sense.
Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind that the output is on separate lines:

```
foo = [["tables", 1, 2], ["ladders", 2, 5], ["chairs", 2]]
for table in foo:
    print "%s %s" %(table[0],", ".join(map(str,table[1:])))
```

To get this all on the same line makes it slightly more difficult:

```
import sys
foo = [["tables", 1, 2], ["ladders", 2, 5], ["chairs", 2]]
for table in foo:
    sys.stdout.write("%s %s " %(table[0],", ".join(map(str,table[1:]))))

print
```

Comment: Also, it's possible to use `end=''` as a parameter in `print` function as of Python 3, or in Python 2 with adding `from __future__ import print_function` statement at the beginning.

Comment: from `__future__ import print_function` appears to be available in 2.6, but not 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.4.x

The following will do it:

```
for item in l:
    print(str(item[0:])[1:-1])
```

where l is your list.

For your input, this prints out:

```
tables 1, 2
ladders 2, 5
chairs 2
```

Another (cleaner) way would be something like this:

```
for item in l:
    value_set = str(item[0:])
    print (value_set[1:-1])
```

Yields the same output:

```
tables 1, 2
ladders 2, 5
chairs 2
```

Hope this helps anyone that may come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
L = [['tables', 1, 2], ['ladders', 2, 5], ['chairs', 2]]
for el in L:
    print('{0} {1}'.format(el[0],', '.join(str(i) for i in el[1:])))
```

The output is:

```
tables 1, 2
ladders 2, 5
chairs 2
```

`{0} {1}` is the output string where

`{0}` is equal to `el[0]` which is `'tables'`, `'ladders'`, ...

`{1}` is equal to `', '.join(str(i) for i in el[1:])`

and `', '.join(str(i) for i in el[1:])` joins each element in the list from these: `[1,2]`, `[2,5]`,... with `', '` as a divider.

`str(i) for i in el[1:]` is used to convert each integer to string before joining.

Comment: This pretty much makes sense, thank you for the explinations, but it also comes up with the same strange output that I responded to the first answer does. It will print something like:

 [['wind', 1, 2], ['blow', 1], ['form', 1], ['south', 1], ['strong', 2]] I got output of: w i, n, d Followed by a traceback error about why an int is not subscriptable

Comment: @user1079404 I don't uderstand what's wrong. The code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This uses pure list comprehensions without `map()`, `re.sub()` or a `for` loop:

```
print '\n'.join((item[0] + ' ' + ', '.join(str(i) for i in item[1:])) for item in l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (Python3)

try:

```
[print(*oneSet, sep=", ") for oneSet in a]
```

For some a:

```
a=[["tables", 1, 2], ["ladders", 2, 5], ["chairs", 2]]
```

print(*list) opens up the list into elements in the print command. You can use a parameter sep=string to set the separator. :)